# What is the difference between Batch and Bash files?

Tags: bash, batch-file

What are the differences between Batch and Bash?

How are they being used?

Comment: See also [differences-between-windows-batch-and-linux-bash-shell-script-syntax](/http://www.xoogu.com/2012/differences-between-windows-batch-and-linux-bash-shell-script-syntax/)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim your link is broken. The url is [http://www.xoogu.com/2012/differences-between-windows-batch-and-linux-bash-shell-script-syntax/](http://www.xoogu.com/2012/differences-between-windows-batch-and-linux-bash-shell-script-syntax/)

Answer (score 40):

"Batch File" is terminology normally used for a text file containing a sequence of MSDOS shell commands. Bash is a unix shell, and normally the equivalent term for unix to "Batch File" is "Shell Script", or simply "Script".

I've never heard the term "Bash file", though it makes some logical sense, usually "Shell Script" or "Bash Script" is used instead.

Comment: Is anyone still using MS-DOS? I think you should write "Windows commands" instead, because nowadays Windows definitely does not include MS-DOS commands (i.e. 16bit) any longer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Windows Command Shell Commands, running in an interpreter based on MSDOS which in turn is based on CP/M. Is anyone still using Unix? no of course not. They're using Linux and Unix derivatives like Mac OS X. But you didn't pick apart my usage of "Unix" there, did you? ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name of course if you wanted to fully update your practices you'd use the Windows Script Host rather than batch files. In which case your file would be called a "Script" :)

Answer (score 11):

"Batch" can mean several things (ignoring the general, non-technical definitions):

- A file containing MS-DOS or Windows command shell instructions in the form of a script. These will have filenames ending in ".BAT" for DOS or Windows or ".CMD" for Windows.
- Linux/Unix also has a `batch` command. This is used to schedule the execution of a process when the system load falls below a threshold.
- Generically, a set of processes run as a group. This definition may be a little more tied to older systems such as those using punched cards, etc.

From `man bash`:

> Bash  is  an  sh-compatible  command language interpreter that executes
>          commands read from the standard input or from a file.  Bash also incorporates useful features from the Korn and C shells (ksh and csh).

It's typically used on Linux or Unix (including OS X) systems, but it can be used on others, including Windows.

Answer (score 7):

`Bash` is actually a shell in UNIX/Linux. Batch files (or batch jobs) are usually referred to files containing list of commands executed periodically (daily, weekly, etc). You can write batch jobs in any language (example, `Python, PHP, Perl, Shell script`). `Bash` shell also supports scripting. So, you can write batch files with `Bash` scripting also.

This is a broad idea without dealing with too much intricacies. :)

Comment: Err, aren't those called cron jobs, or cron tabs, normally, rather than batch jobs or batch files?

Comment: True, they are normally scheduled with `cron` and hence, called `cron jobs`. But people do loosely call them `batch` files also. Many times, `batch` files are referred to files in Windows containing list of `DOS` commands. However, now a days I don't think they are in much use.

Answer (score 4):

Bash is a Unix shell. A bash file is a batch file, but not the other way around. A batch file is a text file containing a series of commands.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)